# Why less db hits still take more time to return response as compared to more db hit in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have done node auto indexing on "customUrl" property. But when I run my query using indexing and without indexing I was surprised that without indexing it took less time as compared to indexing.

Following is the query with indexing.

```
PROFILE Start u = node:node_auto_index("customUrl:vishal") Match (u : User) return u
```

[image]

As you can see it took 677 ms.

Below is the query for without indexing.

```
PROFILE Match (u : User {customUrl : 'vishal'}) return u
```

[image]
This query without indexing and more db hits still took less time. I have read that neo4j caches the response and in subsequent call return the response from cache but unfortunately I didn't saw any lowering in response time of subsequent calls. Do I have to enable the caching explicitly ?

Comment: cold cache vs. warm caches? how often did you run those two?

Comment: @michael-hunger I am not aware about cold cache vs warm caches. I run these two queries  around 7-8 times.

Answer (score 3):

The former statement performs a full index query on lucene. The latter just scans all nodes for the given labels (~200) and applies a filter on that.

The label scan should scale with `O(n)` whereas an index operation should scale with `O(log(n))`. So the more data you have, the better is the benefit from using the index.

When querying manual/auto indexes you have to distinguish between a simple index seek and an full index query:

```
 START u = node:node_auto_index(customUrl = "vishal") RETURN u // seek
 START u = node:node_auto_index("customUrl:vishal") RETURN u // query
```

For details RTFM at http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-start.html. The seek should be faster than the query.

Neo4j does **never** cache query responses, instead nodes, relationships and properties are cached in the [page cache](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/configuration-io-examples.html). This cache is enabled by default and consumes up to 50% of RAM minus the max Java heap size (unless you configure its size explicitly).

Comment: that's why e.g. schema indexes don't bother to check the index if you have fewer than 1000 nodes. Also the start-clause doesn't report the "internal" db-hits in lucene